# Optimizar de .Apk a .aab (Android App Bundle)

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Hoy he actualizado una aplicación de android  .Apk a .aab (Android App Bundle).
Al subir la aplicación .aab en google play console todo funciona bien pero mas tarde me da el consejo: Diseña tu aplicación para tablets….

En las versiones .APK funciona todo correcto y la aplicación funciona para todos los dispositivos y sin consejos, pero al subir la versión .aab me dice este consejo.

**En Android vitals > Tamaño de la aplicación dice:**
Habilita los APK de configuración para distintas densidades de pantalla -Implementado

y

**En Adquisición de usuarios>Consejos de optimización dice:**
Diseña tu aplicación para tablets -Mostrar detalles

La estructura de la aplicación seria:

- drawable
- layout
- layout-sw600dp
- layout-sw720dp
- mipmap-anydpi-v26
- mipmap-hdpi
- mipmap-mdpi
- mipmap-xhdpi
- mipmap-xxhdpi
- mipmap-xxxhdpi
- values
- values-sw600dp
- values-sw720dp

La estructura es correcta?

Algún consejo?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: y has proba tu app en una pantallde 10 pulgadas por ejemplo?

Comment: Buenas, 

Si tengo dos tablets con distintos tamaños y funciona bien. Las versiones .apk google play console me dice todo correcto. Pero con la versión .aab me da el consejo: Diseña tu aplicación para tablets, lo curioso es que al mismo tiempo en Android vitals > Tamaño de la aplicación dice:
Habilita los APK de configuración para distintas densidades de pantalla-**Implementado**.

Creo que me podría faltar algún directorio en la estructura de la aplicación.
Estoy un poco perdido.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que tu aplicación se adapte a cualquier pantalla puedes implementar diferentes tipos de layout en tu proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quieres que tu app sea responsive puedes usar `ConstraintLayout` sin necesidad de agregar un directorio para cada tipo de pantalla (creo que es lo mejor)

podes crear varios tipos de tamaño de pantalla y densidad y si creas el .aab solo bajaría el tipo de pantalla que necesita a diferencia de .apk que baja todo al dispositivo

Comment: Interesante! podría ser este el motivo del mensaje. Voy a realizar algunas pruebas a ver si es este el problema, de todas formas la aplicación .aab me funciona con todos los dispositivos. 
Muchas gracias por la información.